# How do I update output.outputFile.name.replace for Gradle 4.1?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have a Gradle script that needs to be updated to run with a newer version.  I understand that outputFile is now a read only property, and have updated references to it in some of my build files.  I have this snippet of code and I can't figure out how to get it to run in Gradle 4.1 (I've just begun learning Gradle/Groovy).  Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace("-release-unsigned", "")
                )
            }
        }
    }

    debug {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace("-debug", "")
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${variant.name}.apk"
            }
        }
    }

    debug {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${variant.name}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
}
```